# What chili variety is this?

Tags: identification, chili

I'm growing several varieties of chili peppers at home. One of my plants seems to like the local climate more than the others and it fruits a lot more often. Thing of, I'm not sure what variety it is. It grew from a seed I took out of a store-bought pepper I used for cooking. At the store, it was just labelled as *hot pepper* (sic!)

I'm pretty sure it's a cultivar of *Capsicum annuum*, one of the so-called Cayenne peppers.

The fruits grow downward. They're initially green, then they turn black and finally red as they ripen.

The leaves are a lot narrower than those of my *Capsicum chinense* varieties, more similar to my Chocolate cherry plant in shape and colour.

[image: fruits and a leaf shown on an outstretched palm]

Is this the *bird's eye chili*?

Comment: Could be a jalapeño as they turn black before red and it looks very similar to the one I have in my greenhouse.

Comment: @Shambhala doesn't look like any jalapeño I've seen. They're usually round and more stubby than these.